# How to load a JS file via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something very weird happening in my app.

I need to load a JS through $.getScript because I need to load it dynamically.

If I load it through html like

```
<script src="http://otherproject/project/test.js"></script>
```

everything works.

However, if I load it through `$.getScript(http://otherproject/project/test.js)`

I got `undefined is not a function` error.

Here is my JS

test.js

```
Myproject = (typeof Myproject !== "undefined") ? Myproject : {};

Myproject.common = (typeof Myproject.common !== "undefined") ? Myproject
.common : {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    TEST = new Myproject.common.Init(); 
    // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function here
});

Myproject.common.Init = (typeof Myproject.common.Init !== "undefined") ? Myproject
.common.Init : (function() {
//more codes…..
```

I don't know how to solve this as my brain really fried now. Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What line do you get the `undefined is not a function` error? When you use a debugger, what isn't defined? `getScript`? Have you checked that `$` is what you think it is?

Comment: TEST = new Myproject.common.Init();  is where i got the error

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorthand Ajax function, you need to use callbacks since it is asynchronous

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Example callback structure above^

`jQuery.getScript( url [, success ] )` <-- chain promises to make more call backs. or write your own.

`$.getScript(http://otherproject/project/test.js)`

^ this is not using a callback and not correct since your URL parameter is not of type String. Hence why your code doesn't know what the functions in it are...

[jQuery Documentation for getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: I already used your codes here and still got me the same undefined is not a function error. :( +1 though

Comment: Post update in your question with new code...we'll get you through it